# How to find Arrays element > to X in objective-c with predicateWithFormat?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Excuse my stupid question, I did'nt find any simple tutorial ... 
How do I find via NPredicate the elements in an simple array that are > to something (int value)

here MyArray contents are simple : "100,101,102,100,90,91..." etc.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF >= %@", @"100"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [MyArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

It always returns me , the original Array

Comment: Is your array NSStrings array or NSNumbers array?

Comment: `@"100"` is a string.

Comment: it's an array of strings

Answer (score 0):

Here you can filter the Array using Predicate

> [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourValue.intValue >= %d", [filterSquareFootage intValue]]

First You have to convert your comparison value from NSString to NSInteger so that comparison should work properly but If you will compare via NSString then it will not give you proper result because It will then compare two Strings.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND the correct syntax : SELF <=> the Array element, a string so if i Want to compare its integerValue I have to use "SELF.integerValue"

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.integerValue >= %d", [Mystring integerValue]];